# React JS add values to const value from another file

Tags: python, reactjs

I have one file **SidebarData.tsx**

```
export const SidebarData = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      path: '/',
      icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />  
    }, 
    {
      title: 'Sales',
      path: '/crm/sales/',
      icon: <FaIcons.FaCartPlus />
    }  
    }, 
  ]
```

I want to add login and logout in some condition in another file. Which is using this SidebarData const and apply in to making sidebar menu in reactJS. But it shows error for can not assign value to const variable.

Here is my Navigation Sidebar menu file code :  **Navigation.tsx**

```
    import {SidebarData} from './SidebarData'
    
    interface NavigationProps {
      showLoginBtn: boolean
    }
    
   

let Navigation = (props: NavigationProps) => {
 

    if (props.showLoginBtn) { 
       
     
   }
  else {
     data  = [
      ...SidebarData,
      {
        title: 'Logout',
        path: 'http://localhost:8000/logout',
        icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome /> 
      }
    ]
  }

 
  
  return( 
    <nav className="navbar-default navbar-static-side main-navigation" role="navigation">
      <div className="title-header">
        <div className="logo-container" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          <img src={logo} width="70%" />
          <h2>CEO-ME</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebar-collapse">
          <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
           
            <SidebarNav >
              <SidebarWrap>
                <NavIcon to='#'> 
                    <img src={logo} width="70%" /> 
                </NavIcon>
                {data.map((item :any, index :any) => {
                  return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} />;
                })}
              </SidebarWrap>
            </SidebarNav>
          </IconContext.Provider>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "50px" }}>
          <div className="font-size: 0.6rem">
              <strong>Current System Time</strong><br />
          </div>
          <strong>Secured and protected by</strong><br />
          <img src="https://www.cloudflare.com/img/logo-cloudflare-dark.svg" style={{width: "150px"}} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  ) 

};
export default Navigation
```

There is issue in adding login / logout in  SidebarData = []. How to resolve that

Comment: You can take that values in a variable.

Comment: If these sort of data can be changed, then i think the best you can do is put these data in to a state

Comment: You need to clarify, are you looking to actually modify the file in the file system? or would you like to modify it in memory once you import it from the file?

Comment: I have update the code. I want to add some data into predefined array dynamically that I am using them into further code

Answer (score 0):

How about define SideBarData as a Function?:

```
 export const SidebarData = (showLoginBtn) => [
    showLoginBtn ? {
        title: 'Login',
        path: '/login',
        icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />   
     } : {
        title: 'Logout',
        path: '/logout',
        icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome /> 
      },
    {
      title: 'Home',
      path: '/',
      icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />  
    }, 
    {
      title: 'Sales',
      path: '/crm/sales/',
      icon: <FaIcons.FaCartPlus />
    }  
    }, 
  ];
```

Then, in your Navigation file:

```
import {SidebarData} from './SidebarData'
    
interface NavigationProps {
  showLoginBtn: boolean
}
    
let Navigation = (props: NavigationProps) => ( 
    <nav className="navbar-default navbar-static-side main-navigation" 
     role="navigation">
      <div className="title-header">
        <div className="logo-container" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          <img src={logo} width="70%" />
          <h2>CEO-ME</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="sidebar-collapse">
          <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
            <SidebarNav >
              <SidebarWrap>
                <NavIcon to='#'> 
                    <img src={logo} width="70%" /> 
                </NavIcon>
                {SidebarData(props.showLoginBtn).map((item :any, index :any) => {
                  return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} />;
                })}
              </SidebarWrap>
            </SidebarNav>
          </IconContext.Provider>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "50px" }}>
          <div className="font-size: 0.6rem">
              <strong>Current System Time</strong><br />
          </div>
          <strong>Secured and protected by</strong><br />
          <img src="https://www.cloudflare.com/img/logo-cloudflare-dark.svg" style={{width: "150px"}} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: It looks like you updated the code in your question, let me update my answer based on it

Comment: @DaminiSuthar . It's done. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add another variable and we can use that to bind data :

```
interface NavigationProps {
  showLoginBtn: boolean
} 


let Navigation = (props: NavigationProps) => {
  let links = []
    if (props.showLoginBtn) { 
      links = [
        {
          title: 'Login',
          path: backendURL + "login/",
          icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />   
        },
        ...SidebarData
      ]
    }
  else {
    links  = [
      ...SidebarData,
      {
        title: 'Logout',
        path: backendURL + "logout/",
        icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />  
      }
    ]
  }
  
  return( 
    <nav className="navbar-default navbar-static-side main-navigation" role="navigation"> 
      <div className="sidebar-collapse">
          <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
           
            <SidebarNav >
              <SidebarWrap>
                <NavIcon to='#'> 
                    <img src={logo} width="70%" /> 
                </NavIcon>
                { links.map((item, index) => {
                  return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} />
                })}
              </SidebarWrap>
            </SidebarNav>
          </IconContext.Provider>
      
      </div>
      
    </nav>
  ) 
}

export default Navigation
```